# Tool to automatically modify Windows 7 theme colors by time of day?

Tags: windows-7, macos, firefox, colors, themes

I just started using f.lux because I've been having insomnia issues and it seems to be helping immensely.  I'd like to take it one step further and find something that can change my windows 7 theme colors to dark when the sun goes down.  So during the day I can have my bright light-blue taskbar, window frames, etc... and when nighttime rolls around everything will switch to dark mode.  Something like what happens on a Garmin GPS when the sun goes down, basically the colors reverse and it goes into night mode.

OS X and Firefox suggestions are extremely welcome as well, since I use both a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem to be very easy.

Some example scripts for setting the theme from the commandline are [shown here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=38589). You could then use a Scheduled Task to do the switching.

Comment: awesome, i'll check that out... if i get it to work i'll mark this as answered.

Comment: just for full disclosure, I never had time to mess with this, but the link looked promising enough to mark the question as answered.  If anyone ever happens to try this please provide a comment and I can revise.